# Height of Java Diamond Asterisk

Tags: java, for-loop, height, width

How can i get this code to display the height correctly? So if the width of the diamond asterisk is 3, and the height is 5, then the diamond will look like this.

```
     *
    ***
    ***
    ***
     *
```

It just adds any excess height to the middle. Here is my code so far. It can do the width just fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int width, height, heightT;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter width of diamond (odd number between 0-19): ");
        width = scan.nextInt();
        if (width % 2 != 0) {
            if (0 <= width && width <= 19) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter height of diamond (greater than or equal to width): ");
        height = scan.nextInt();
        if(height >= width) {
            heightT = height - width;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < width + 1; i += 2) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    for(int i = width - 2; i > 0; i -= 2) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: its good to point the problem directly

Comment: So does that mean I did it correctly, or should I highlight the part that I can't get in my code? @SSH

Comment: What does your output look like when you input 3 and 5?

Comment: @Alexander my output is a basic diamond, the height function isnt used at all yet, that is what i need help on. To make the logic in it.

Comment: Ok, let me dig up some old code from an assignment I had about making diamonds.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a working code sample. Feel free to accept it if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When solving this type of logic you have to always look at the things that you know **never** change. In this case, **3 things never change**:

**1. The first line.** Always equal to one asterisk.

**2. The middle line.** Always equal to width in asterisks.

**3. The last line.** Always equal to one asterisk.

Now, **split** the diamond in two by the middle row. Notice the **total height will always be the height of the top part (or bottom) times 2 plus 1 (the middle row)**. You get something more less like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; ((i*2)+1) <= height; i++){
        //Print top
    }

    // Print middle row outside of loops or inside if you must.

    for(int i = 0; ((i*2)+1) <= height; i++){
        //Print bottom.
    }
```

**EDIT:** This would only be true for diamonds where height is greater than or equal to the width.

**EDIT:** This code solves your problem (given height is greater than or equal to width). However, it **does not handle** `width = 0` or `width = 1` properly. I trust that would be trivial enough for you to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int height = 9, width = 9;
    int spaces = (width - 1) / 2, asterisks = 1;



    for(int i = 0;((i*2)) < height; i++){
        for(int ii = 0;ii < spaces;ii++){
           System.out.print(" ");  
        }
        for(int ii = 0;ii < asterisks;ii++){
           System.out.print("*");
        }
    spaces--;
    if(asterisks < width)asterisks += 2;
    System.out.println();
    }

    spaces = 0;

    for(int i = 0; ((i*2)+1) < height; i++){
        if(width < height){
            for(int ii = 0;ii < spaces;ii++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int ii = 0;ii < asterisks;ii++){
               System.out.print("*");
            }
        }else{
            for(int ii = 0;ii < (spaces + 1);ii++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int ii = 0;ii < (asterisks - 2);ii++){
               System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    spaces++;
    asterisks -= 2;
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still confused. What do i fill inside the top, bottom, and middle portion

Comment: @Armdev The other for-loops to print asterisks. These for-loops are to handle each row to "keep track" of how many we have to print (which is the height restriction).

Comment: Can you just give me the code? My mind is literally blanking out right now. Or use parts of my code to implement?

Comment: @Armdev I haven't forgotten about you.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference between height and width and reuse your logic in a while loop.

```
for(int i = 1; i < width + 1; i += 2) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)

        System.out.print(" ");

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");

    System.out.print("\n");
}
int dif = height-width;
 while(dif !=0){
 for(int i = width; i < width + 1; i += 2) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)

        System.out.print(" ");

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");

    System.out.print("\n");
}
 dif--;
 }
for(int i = width - 2; i > 0; i -= 2) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");

    System.out.print("\n");
}
```